# Sobolev space of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f(x) = √x$  denote the square root function. For what m ∈ {1, 2, 3 . . . } and $p ∈ [1,∞)$ values is it true that $$f ∈ W^{m,p}(1,∞)?$$

I just tried like this by using integration by parts: $\int_{1}^\infty\varphi'(x)\sqrt{x}\,dx = [\varphi(x)\sqrt x]_1^\infty - \int_1^\infty \varphi(x)\cdot\frac 1 {2\sqrt x}\,dx = -\int_1^\infty \varphi(x)\cdot\frac 1 {2\sqrt x}\,dx.$

So, the weak derivative of $√x$ is $1/(2\sqrt x)$, which is an element of $L^p(1,\infty)$ and $f$ is differentiable for all orders of m. What's wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Just review the definition of Sobolv spaces!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is not in $ L^p(1,\infty)$, so it cannot be in $W^{m,p}(1,\infty)$

Comment: Thanks.. that was my confusion. So for what values of $m$ and $n$ the function $f$ belongs to $W^{m,p}(1,\infty)?$

Comment: @UserAb : None. (unless you consider negative $m$)

Comment: @Tryss....Thank you! I get it  now